# Unable to get form to open to an existing record

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, record

When my application first opens, I have an Autoexec Macro set to open a small form (frmGrantNo) in a window that asks for a grant number, the field for the grant number opens blank (Data Entry = On).  This works.

Next I want to manually enter an existing Grant Number from my table (tblGrant), and open another form (frmInfo) to the grant number I manually entered.

So far, if I manually enter an existing Grant Number, I can’t get it to take me to that record in the frmInfo form, it opens to the first record in the table.

I have tried a Button Wizard for a Go To Record Button and I get the error “The command or action “Find” isn’t available now”.

I have tried a macro that opens the table (tblGrant), then Got To record, then Open Form (frmInfo) and it opens the table in datasheet AND the frmInfo Form, but to the first record, not the one I entered.

I have tried event procedures that I found online, but none of them work as I still don’t quite understand more than the basic VB commands.

I have looked here for help but I may not be working my questions right becuase I haven't found anything to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. ~ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInfo", WhereCondition:="GrantNumber = " & Me!GrantNumber
```

in the button event procedure. It filters the opened form to the grant number you entered. Adapt field names for your table and form.